How to use terra::tapp in 2 consecutives year
I have a set of raster. I would like to apply a function from 2001-01-01 to 2002-12-31 then 2002-01-01 to 2003-12-31. (Two years each time). Is it possible with tapply function (I have something with a loop but it is quite slow).
  rast_stack <- sapply(1:1826, function(i) rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10))
    rast_stack<-rast(rast_stack)
    rast_stack[]<-rnorm(n=ncell(rast_stack))
    terra::time(rast_stack)<-seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2005-12-31"),by="day")

 Myfunction <- function(TempRast,TDMIN,TDMAX,TCXSTOP){
  X<-TempRast
  X[is.na(TempRast)|is.nan(TempRast)]<-0
  udevc<-TempRast
  udevc[]<-NA
  udevc[X<= TDMIN]<-0
  udevc[TDMIN< X & X< TDMAX]<-X[TDMIN< X & X< TDMAX]- TDMIN
  udevc[TDMAX <= X & X < TCXSTOP]<-(TDMAX - TDMIN) / (TDMAX - TCXSTOP)   (X[TDMAX <= X & X < TCXSTOP] - TCXSTOP)
  udevc[X>= TCXSTOP]<-0
  udevc[is.na(TempRast)|is.nan(TempRast)]<-NA
  return(udevc)
}

I would like something like :
res<-tapp(rast_stack,2yearsIndex,myfunction)


How many values does myfunction return and how many layers do you expect after it is applied?

I add the function editing the post. myfunction return a stack raster with the same number of layer of TempRast, so 730 layers

terra::tapp has build-in support that allows computing a summary statistic for standard periods such as "years" and "months", but not for "two-years" period.
However, like in tapply and stats::aggregate, you can construct your own index to summarize your data.
Your example data
library(terra)
r <- rast(nl=1826, nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10)
set.seed(1)
values(r) <- rnorm(size(r))
time(r) <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2005-12-31"), by="day")

Create an index from the years. Each even year is renamed to the previous (odd) year to get two-year periods.
yrs <- as.integer(format(time(r), "%Y"))
i <- ((yrs %% 2) == 0)
yrs[i] <- yrs[i] - 1
yrs <- paste0("Y", yrs, "_", yrs+1)

Use terra::tapp
x <- tapp(r, yrs, mean)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       :  Y2001_2002, Y2003_2004, Y2005_2006 
#min values  : -0.08979350, -0.1034173, -0.1411041 
#max values  :  0.08894972,  0.1243632,  0.1389769 

I am not correcting for the fact that the example data ends in 2005.
If you do not wish to summarize your data, then tapp is not the method you are looking for.
You could write a loop like
uyrs <- unique(yrs)
out <- lapply(uyrs, \(y) {
      x <- r[[yrs == y]]
      # add some logic based on the value of y?
      x * 2
   })  |> rast()

out 
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1826  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       :     lyr.1,     lyr.2,     lyr.3,     lyr.4,     lyr.5,     lyr.6, ... 
#min values  : -4.429400, -3.828719, -5.777841, -5.184655, -6.016097, -5.057001, ... 
#max values  :  4.803236,  4.615957,  5.298334,  3.942675,  7.620553,  4.049684, ... 
#time (days) : 2001-01-01 to 2005-12-31 

Inside the lapply loop, you may want to use terra::app. To do so, first write a function that has your reclassification logic and work on a vector of input values.

And should the OP forego his expectation of a 'daily' value, as it seemed rather (again perhaps) 01/01/2001 as against 01/01/2002, which would still have net reduced layers returned.

Thanks, the question did not specify that. I now see that this is mentioned in the comments. In that case tapp would not apply and I have added another route that might cover what the OP is after.

Thanks a lot, I need both of your solution for part of my code so thanks. However, there is still a litle issue, I need sliding year as index. So Index 1 would be 2002-2003 index 2 would be 2003-2004. I tried to make it but cannot  do it for now. If you have any solution i would be gratefull

You would have to run terra::tapp twice and then combine the output
